# Refresh only a few lines on Bash Script

Tags: bash

So this is my output...

```
00-
01-  Wallet : 123456789123465789 
02- 
03- --------------------
04- Server Stats Update:
05- --------------------
06-  Work Units : 0 (cancelled:0 | completed:0) 
07-  Average Complete Time : 0 
08- 
09- -------------
10- Stats Update:
11- -------------
12-  Work Units : 0 (ondemand:0 | precache:0 | paid:0) 
13-  Prize Pool : 0%    -    Earned : 0 
14-
```

I need the lines 06,07,12 and 13 to keep refreshing... the only method I found so far is by making a loop and clearing the output every two seconds...

Also I found that `printf \033[A` could be useful but I couldn't figure how to implement it here...

My code...

```
while true: do
  echo -e "\n Wallet : ${Address} \n"
  echo --------------------
  echo Server Stats Update:
  echo --------------------
  echo -e " Work Units : ${ServerOverallWU} (cancelled:${Cancelled} | completed:${Completed}) "
  echo -e " Average Complete Time : ${AvgCompTime} "
  echo
  echo -------------
  echo Stats Update:
  echo -------------
  echo -e " Work Units : ${SaveOverallWU} (ondemand:${SaveOnDemand} | precache:${SavePreCache} | paid:${SavePaidWU}) "
  echo -en " Prize Pool : ${SavePrizePool}%   -    Earned : ${SaveEarned} "
done
```

Ps: Fixed... just put the clear on the right stop and now it runs smooth as butter

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210325/333919

Comment: Once you echo something at terminal, this can't be really "refreshed". Instead, did you try [watching](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) your script?

Comment: @Tané What is your definition of "refreshed". Many programs do something that I would call "refreshing" (eg. `top`, `vim`).

Comment: Was a poor definition, my bad. Watch and even echo do, for example: `echo -e -n "first\r"; sleep 2; echo "refresh!"`. But I was trying to give a answer related with @anderson code

Answer (score 1):

If you want complete control over your screen, you can probably `clear` it at the beginning of the script and then use direct cursor addressing to only repaint parts of the screen (i.e. move the cursor to position 1,13; repaint that line to replace it; then move to line 15 and repaint that) but this will be rather ugly and painful in pure Bash. Perhaps you should use a `curses` wrapper like `whiptail` to shield you from the details. Maybe see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155417/a-set-of-libraries-like-ncurses-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

I've got a function for that

```
XY () { printf "\e[$2;${1}H$3"; }
```

Usage

```
XY 1 13 "Hello World!"
```

It'll print 'Hello World!' on column 1 of line 13.
Comparing this with `tput`

```
for i in {1..100}; {
    tput cup $1 $2; printf "Hello World!"
}

real    0m0,130s
user    0m0,079s
sys     0m0,055s


for i in {1..100}; {
    XY $1 2 "Hello World!"
}

real    0m0,002s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,000s
```

Comment: In practice this is purely academic, but I'll note that the terminal driver offers the `tput` command for *portably* emitting screen control codes. Unless you are into computer archaeology, hardcoding VT100 control codes is probably going to work pretty much everywhere.